# Memory leak when defining a variable

Tags: javascript

I would like to know why jsLint is complaining that I might be leaking a variable when defining some variables like this:

```
var foo = bar = {};
```

It says I might be leaking `bar`.

My hunch is that it is because `bar` is global variable. Then, how can I assign `foo` and `bar` to point to the same object in one line? JavaScript won't let me write:

```
var foo = var bar = {};
```

Or is the issue something else?

Comment: How about: `var bar = {}, foo = bar;` ?

Comment: You really want `foo` and `bar` to refer to **the same object**?!

Comment: @deceze I don't see any reason for that but I was curious while following a JavaScript tutorial.

Comment: if you're trying to alias `bar` for a local scope your code is fine

Comment: What is the exact warning that JSLint is producing? I tried your code at jslint.com, and didn't get anything about "leaking a variable". It complained that `bar` is not declared, and about using `=` in an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's complaining about "leaking a variable" is because you're only declaring the local variable `foo`. `bar` is not being declared, it's just being assigned, so this creates a global variable. Your statement is equivalent to:

```
var foo = (bar = {});
```

which is short for:

```
bar = {};
var foo = bar;
```

Written that way, you can see that there's no declaration of the `bar` variable. If you want to declare multiple variables in a single `var` statement, you must separate them with commas:

```
var bar = {}, foo = bar;
```

Or you can write them as separate statements:

```
var bar = {};
var foo = bar;
```

You could also separate the declarations and assignments:

```
var foo, bar;
foo = bar = {};
```

Comment: I wrote this quick test `(function(){
    var notLeakedA = "A", notLeakedB = "B";
    veryMuchLeakedC = "C";
})();` and outside the IIFE, only `veryMuchLeakedC` was accessible.

Comment: @IgweKalu That's expected. `var` declares local variables, they aren't accessible outside the function.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

```
var foo = {},
    bar = {};
```

Or:

```
var foo, bar;
foo = bar = {};
```

The first one creates individual objects for `foo` and `bar`.
In the second example, both `foo` and `bar` point to the *same* object.

You can't *(/shouldn't try to)* declare *and* assign multiple variables using a single `var` statement, *and* a single object literal, on one line. Then you're just declaring multiple variables that point to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

Best approach would be :

```
var foo = {} , bar = {};
```

But `foo` and `bar` would refer to two different objects.

If you want them to refer to the same object, then:

```
var foo = {}, bar = foo;
```